# "AWT-EventQueue-0" NullpointerException inconsistent error message

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, paintcomponent

I'm getting this error message when im starting my Java application:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at engine.Display.GamePanel.paintComponent(GamePanel.java:102)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The application doesn't close and it lets me run it normally and there is no visual buggs etc etc but i still get this error message SOMETIMES when i start the application.

The only peice of my own code it points me to is line 102 in my GamePanel class which is my paintComponent method here:

```
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //g.drawImage(test, picX, picY, picSizeX, picSizeY, null);
    mao.Draw(picX, picY, g);
}
```

And inside the mao.Draw we have this:

```
    public void Draw(int x, int y, Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(characterImage, x, y, null);
        g2d.drawRect(x, y, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

I have tinkered around with this problem but i cannot seem to find the error.

Comment: mao.Draw(picX, picY, g); is about bad practicies, don't to create, init&lize any Object from paintComponent, prepare those Object before put all Objects to array(s) and inside paintComponent to loop inside this array, repaint() should be called programatically (on EDT)

Comment: @mKorbel I have a really hard time to understand what you are saying, Can you clearify what you mean with your whole message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being caused in line 102 of GamePanel.java which I believe is

```
  mao.Draw(picX, picY, g);
```

because `mao` is not yet initialized, that is, has the value `null` when the method is called. Probably your application is not fully initialized but the GamePanel is already being displayed.

You can do the following to check if that is the case:

```
if (mao != null) {
    mao.Draw(picX, picY, g);
}
```

Comment: You were right and this was the case, Is it bad practice to leave it like this in my paintComponent or would it be better to change it up for more efficient code?

Comment: depends: if the instance in `mao` is not being changed I would prefer to have it initialized before showing the GUI; if it is changed (e.g. by user interaction) I'd prefer the solution with `if`. Since it apparently is a Game Panel, it probably would be more appropriate to have it created beforehand

Comment: I am initializing mao = new Mao(); before it is being drawn but i am not sure why it is still being null

Answer (score 1):

The exception is `NullPointerException` in your `paintComponent()` method.

So the problem is there, not in your `Draw()` method. In `paintComponent()` you access the `mao` identifier which I assume is an attribute (of the `GamePanel` class).

All painting in Swing is done on the EDT thread, and I assume you initialize and set this `mao` attribute NOT on the EDT thread => this is a synchronization issue. Either assign the `mao` attribute on the EDT thread, or make it synchronized so that multiple threads accessing it properly see its true value.

You get this exception once or rare occasions and your application works, because only the `paintComponent()` will be aborted, but subsequent attempts to paint your component might succeed (if the `mao` becomes finally visible by the EDT thread or was modified meanwhile).